# Set position for \maketitle in article

Tags: positioning, titles

I want to create a handout to support a speech I have to give.

Since I am only familiar with the `\documentclass{article}`, I wrote the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\PrerenderUnicode{äöüÄÖÜß}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{Some title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{2.7.2012}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}    
    \vspace*{-5pt}
    \maketitle

    \subsection*{Text \& Author}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foobar
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

What I want is to have the title, author, date etc. directly on the upper edge of the paper. I understand, there will be more elegant ways to solve this, anyway: 
This `\vspace*{-5pt}` generates an empty page before the actual content of my handout.

Why does it, how can I prevent it to do or (which would be best to know) what is the more elegant way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`article` class defines the single column version of `\maketitle` to effectively begin with `\newpage` You could redefine `\maketitle` but simpler, for a one-off document is just locally disable `\newpage`

```
 \begin{document}    
    \vspace*{-5pt}
    {\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}
\subsection*{Text \& Author}
```

does what you need

Answer (score 6):

You have to redefine the `\@maketitle` macro so that it doesn't add vertical spaces (for example, not using the `center` environment):

```
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \vspace*{-\topskip}      % remove the initial space
  \begingroup\centering    % instead of \begin{center}
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \hrule height \z@        % to avoid the insertion of lineskip glue
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em 
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em 
    {\large \@date}%
  \par\endgroup            % instead of \end{center}
  \vskip 1.5em             % <--- modify this to adjust the separation
}
\makeatother
```

The last `\vskip` command is responsible for the separation between the title and the text.

Comment: Thanks. I have `.sty` file I include to many documents. Thanks to your solution I've managed to rescue space above title in all files at once ! :)

Answer (score 4):

The [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package provides a simple user interface to titling information, and allows you to restyle both the `\title` and the `\thanks`, including moving their position.

The package provides a `\droptitle` length which determines the height of the title line relative to the default.  In your case you want to move the title up, so you can supply a negative space.  In the example below I've loaded the `geometry` package with the `[showframe]` option just to show the relative positioning on the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\PrerenderUnicode{äöüÄÖÜß}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-2cm}
\title{Some title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{2.7.2012}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}    
    \maketitle

    \subsection*{Text \& Author}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item foobar
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]